# Convert array of objects to csv-like format (d3)

Tags: javascript, r, d3.js, rcharts, dimple.js

I have modified a dimple JS script I found on the web to suit my particular needs, and it is currently working when I launch it as an HTML file. Here is my code:

http://pastebin.com/DDrG1w8X

Now I am trying to integrate this custom chart into R using rCharts, following [this](http://timelyportfolio.github.io/rCharts_d3_horizon/) excelent tutorial by TimelyPortfolio.

My problem is the following: on the HTML version of the chart, I was loading the data I plotted using d3.csv. Now on R charts, when I pass on the data as r$set(data = item_series), where item_series is my dataframe that has the same format as the csv file, it gets transformed into an object with the following structure:

```
Object {scraper_name: Array[21], date: Array[21], items: Array[21]}
```

Since my script is made to work with the input data as d3.csv, **I would like to get this object transformed back gain into a tabular format**. How can I achieve this?

Hope the description is clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that if I use:

```
dataset = toJSONArray(item_series, json = F)
```

then I can get rid of the d3.csv(...) function, and simply run the rest of the script using `dataset` as reference. To provide more details:

On R:

```
dataset = toJSONArray(item_series, json = F)
r$set(data = dataset)
```

On my html/js file:

```
data = params.data;
// Now there's no need to use d3.csv, we can process the data directly.
// d3.csv(params.data, function (data) {
var scraper_names = dimple.getUniqueValues(data, "scraper_name");
// }
```